# Adjust Date values based on a parameter value in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

We have a `SSRS` report with `Year , Start-Date, End-Date` Fields ( Start-Date and  End-Date are `Date` controls and `Year` is a `Combo` Value). I need the value of Start-Date and End-Date  to be Restricted based on `Year` value.

For eg: If the Year value is `2016`, then the Start-Date and End-Date value should be between `01/01/2016` and `12/31/2016`.

How to do this in `SSRS`?. Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the Year value to determine if `StartDate` and `EndDate` are dates between `Year`. Using a expression you can get the year from `StartDate` and compare it against `Year` value, based on that comparision you can set another parameter (`StartDateHidden`) which is hidden for users and populated depending on the comparision.

Expression for `StartDateHidden`.

```
=IIF(
  Paramaters!StartDate.Value.Year = Parameters!Year.Value,
  Paramaters!StartDate.Value,DateSerial(Parameters!Year.Value,1,1)
)
```

Note it populates `StartDateHidden` with the `StartDate` value if it is a date in `Year` value, otherwise it will set the first date of the `Year` value.

You can use any default value for cases when `StartDate` is not in the Year value.

Expression for `EndDateHidden`.

```
=IIF(
  Parameters!EndDate.Value.Year = Parameters!Year.Value,
  Parameters!EndDate.Value,DateSerial(Parameters!Year.Value,12,31)
)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: thanks. where can i use this startdatehidden and enddatehidden hidden paramters?

Comment: @bmsqldev, just create two parameters of date/time type (StartDateHidden and EndDateHidden) and set it `Hidden` in the visibility property in order to avoid users touch them. In default values use the expression I posted for every parameter. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: thanks.. additionally i need to create two more parameters right? startdate and enddate

Comment: @bmsqldev, Yes, `StartDate` and `EndDate` are visible parameters to the users, `StartDateHidden` and `EndDateHidden` are hidden. In total four parameters. Use the hidden parameters in your query since they will hold the validated dates between the `Year` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished with one drawback. Your date picker will no longer be a calendar it will be a drop down list with the dates.

Create a query that produces the list of dates you are looking for and add it to the report as a data set. Then in the properties of your Start-Date and End-Date report parameters click on the default values pane. Choose get values from query, select the appropriate dataset, value field, and label field.

After that when you run the report you will have a drop down with the list of dates your query returned. Just make sure you make your dates query dependant on the year report parameter.